# Hidden select box doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome

I have a serious problem with select boxes in Chrome.

I have a hidden DIV with a form containing a SELECT box in it. The DIV is hidden with css `"display:none"`.
I then have a button which shows the hidden DIV on click using jQuery: `$("#addForm").show()`

The problem is, the SELECT box doesn't work when the DIV is shown. :-o
I can see the SELECT box, but the default value is empty and when I click the SELECT box, Chrome do highlight it, but the list of OPTIONs doesn't appear.

If I remove the "`display: none;`" from the CSS, it works. When I then instead hide the `#addForm DIV` on `init` and right after show it again, it's the same problem. As if the CSS corrupts the SELECT box somehow.

This ONLY happens in Chrome. :-/

I thought this would be a common issue, but I haven't managed to find any answers to why it happens, nor a solution.

Can anyone please help me?

---

UPDATE:

In my progress of putting up some code as requested in the comments, I found the bug. :-)

I won't keep you out of it, so here's the code: [www.dehold.net/chrome/](http://www.dehold.net/chrome/)

The script that apparantly destroyed my select boxes was these two lines:

```
$("#mee_empId option").attr('selected',false);
$("#mee_conId option").attr('selected',false);
```

Does anyone have a good solution to do what I'm failing to do correctly?

Comment: Could you provide more information? Demo page, source etc.?

Comment: What a strange issue. I would love to see a demo.

Comment: Could you please post some of your code (either on here or on http://pastebin.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why the page doesn't have a Doctype?

I don't know how JQuery sets attributes but `selected` can never be `false`.
Either the attribute is only present (HTML) or it is set to "selected" (XHTML) or it is absent.

Maybe it was your problem.

Comment: Woops I forgot to put back the doctype. I tried to use the exclusion method to find the problem (the doctype wasn't it).

Comment: Ah yes that would be significantly smarter :-)

Comment: Yeah with that the attribute is really removed ^^

Comment: Thanks Mat - appreciate it :)